# How to Attach a Google Spreadsheet to an Email

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to attach an already created spreadsheet and email it. I have found out that, if I try

```
  opts.fileIds.forEach(function(fileId) {
    console.log('fileId ' + fileId);
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
    var blob = file.getAs(file.getMimeType());
    console.log('blob length' + blob.getDataAsString().length);
    console.log('file retrieved size ' + file.getSize());
    console.log('file mime type ' + file.getMimeType());
    attachmentList.push(blob);
  });
```

I do not get a blob object, file.getAs returns a null however, file.getBlob works fine but turns it into a pdf which is not what I want. Is there any way to attach this a spreadsheet?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

The `attachments` option for [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)) requires an array of [BlobSource objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob-source). If you take a look at the link you can see that Google Files can just be attached without additional work. This includes Spreadsheets, Documents, PDFs, and more.

---

Try just passing back a reference to the file!

```
opts.fileIds.forEach(function(fileId) {
    console.log('fileId ' + fileId);
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);

    //logging
    attachmentList.push(file);
  });
```

---

Edit: The reason for this behaviour by MailApp, *I think* is because [MIMEType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type) and `getAs()` [ContentType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getAs(String)) are different. Take a look at what the Google Scripts site says about https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getAs(String):

> For most blobs, 'application/pdf' is the only valid option.

Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Above just creates a pdf rather than attach spreadsheet. I have changed the body and added it to the email body the url and google automatically shows at the bottom of e-mail properly.